# Boost::asio::async_write doesn't seem to free memory

Tags: c++, networking, boost, boost-asio

I have a cluster program using `boost asio` to make the network part.

I'm using `async_write` function to write the message from the server to the client :

```
boost::asio::async_write( *m_Socket,
    boost::asio::buffer( iData, iSize ),
    boost::bind(
        &MyObject::handle_write, this,
        boost::asio::placeholders::error ) );
```

My `handle_write` method :

```
void
MyObject::handle_write( const boost::system::error_code& error )
{
    std::cout << "handle_write" << std::endl;
    if (error)
    {
        std::cout << "Write error !" << std::endl;
        m_Server->RemoveSession(this);
    }
}
```

It seems to work well. When I use memory leak detector program, there is no leak at all.

But, my program is supposed to run many days without interuption and during test, it appears that I don't have anough memory... After some inspection, I found that my program was allocating around `0.3Mo` by seconds. And with a [memory validor](http://www.softwareverify.com/cpp-memory.php) I found that it was into `boost::asio::async_write`...

I checked the documentation and I think I use it in the correct way... Am I missing something ?

**EDIT 1:**

That is how I call the function who call `async_write` itself :

```
NetworkMessage* msg = new NetworkMessage;

sprintf(msg->Body(), "%s", iData );

m_BytesCount += msg->Length();

uint32 nbSessions = m_Sessions.size();

// Send to all clients
for( uint32 i=0; i < nbSessions; i++)
{
    m_Sessions[i]->Write( msg->Data(), msg->Length() );
 // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
}

delete msg;
```

`msg->Data` is the data passed to `async_write`.

Comment: When you use such solid library as asio you must assume that bug/leak is on your side. Need more code how you use it from accepting to all writes

Comment: @PSIAlt I do, I suppose I don't use `boost::asio` correctly. I saw here some case of "leak" with `async_write` but they don't fit mine ... ([Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994077/boost-async-write-problem)). I'm assuming that there is something here that is wrong...

Comment: please post more code, preferably a [sscce](http://sscce.org) demonstrating the leak. If `async_write()` did leak memory, a lot of applications would be broken...

Comment: What is `iData`, where is it defined?

Comment: @SamMiller I will try to do it even if it is not that simple as I need to do at least a server and a client...

Comment: @IgorR. It is a `const char*`passed in parameter of the function. Look at the edit to see how I call this function.

Comment: This won't work, because `asio::buffer` doesn't copy and doesn't own the underlying buffer - just adapts it to match `ConstBufferSequence` concept. You actual buffer must outlive the async operation.

Comment: @IgorR. My example match their [example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp)... They have a char data_[] in their class and they pass it to async_write... just like me...

Comment: In Asio example they send a buffer, which is an instance *member*, so it lives as long as the containing object does. In your code you pass some buffer and immediately delete it, as far as I see.